# Relativistic velocity addition - algebraic structure?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, group-theory

The relativistic velocity addition $\oplus$ for 3-velocities $\bf{u}$ can be constructed from Lorentz boosts $\Lambda$ acting on 4-velocities $u$

$$ u \to u^\prime = \Lambda(v) \, u \implies \bf{u}^\prime = \bf{v} \oplus \bf{u}. $$

The boost do not form a sub-group or the Lorentz group, neither does $\oplus$ defines a group b/c it misses associativity.

Nevertheless $\oplus$ defines *something* *similar* b/c it has both

1. a neutral element $\bf{v}=0$ and
2. a unique inverse, i.e. for given $\bf{u}, \bf{u}^\prime$ the equation $ \bf{u}^\prime = \bf{v} \oplus \bf{u} $ has a unique solution for $\bf{v}$.

Question: how is this mathematical structure called, and has it been studied somewhere?

Comment: It's probably a loop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loops

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the wiki article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup

1. A *quasi-group* $(G,\oplus)$ is a non-empty set $G$ with binary operation $\oplus$ such that for each $a,b \in G$ there exist unique elements $x,y \in G$ with

$$ a \oplus x = b $$

$$ y \oplus a = b $$

2. A *loop* is a quasi-group with neutral element $e \in G$, such that for all $x \in G$

$$ e \oplus x = x \oplus e = x $$

It follows that the neutral element $e$ is unique and that every element of $G$ has unique left- and right-inverses.

(A loop is as group without associativity)

This holds for the addition $\oplus$ of 3-velocities.

See also *Einstein gyrogroup*, *Cayley–Klein metric*:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.01496v1

Further related articles:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5678v1

https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6961v1

https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0218v1

https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4785v1